# Recorrer un objeto JSON en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array, angular, jsonarray

Estoy un poco perdido de como recorrer el siguiente objeto:

```
    [{   
"0": 
    {
        "modelo": "E40JMHL",
        "nombre_empresa": "COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.",
        "total": 1
    },
"1": 
    {
        "modelo": "F6CMHS",
        "nombre_empresa": "COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.",
        "total": 2
    },
"2":    
    {
        "modelo": "F150FETX",
        "nombre_empresa": "COMERCIO LTDA",
        "total": 1
    },
"3":    
    {
        "modelo": "F20CMHS",
        "nombre_empresa": "COMERCIO LTDA",
        "total": 1
    },
"4":      
    {
        "modelo": "F25GMHL",
        "nombre_empresa": "COMERCIO LTDA",
        "total": 1
    }}]
```

Necesitaba volcar los datos de los modelos en otro array, los totales y la empresa. Por Ejemplo:

```
data_modelo = ['E40JMHL','F6CMHS','F150FETX','F20CMHS','F25GMHL'] ;

data_total = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1] ;


data_empresa = ['COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.' , 'COMERCIO LTDA']
```

Estoy intentando con foreach pero no he logrado ir recorriendo uno por uno. 
Agradecería sus comentarios.

Comment: hola A. V. tu pregunta puedeser cerrada por baja calidad, por favor añade un poco mas sobre que has intentado. lo otro, tu tienes un array de objetos json que son completamente compatible con js, asi que el error se debe mas a lo que estas intentando, intenta con un for recorriendo cada objeto del array (array[i])  para acceder a cada atributo puedes hacerlo mediante u n punto. Ejemplo: Array[i].modelo, ya en es este punto solo seria añadir, ejemplo data_modelo.push(Array[i].modelo);, i viene siendo la indexación del for.

Comment: Hola A V. No estás tratando de recorrer un objeto, sino un arreglo, verdad ? Por qué tienes esa estructura ? No sería mejor tener un arreglo de objetos ? Tipo: [ { }, { }, { }, ... ]

Comment: Hola. Si podrías poner el snippet de código de ejemplo de lo que has intentando. A. Medina tiene razón, pero si la estructura original te llega como el ejemplo puedes intentarlo con reduce: const resultado = tucoleccion.reduce((res, cur, idx) => { res.data_modelo.push(cur[idx].modelo); /* resto de mapeo */; return res }, { data_modelo: [], data_total: [], data_empresa: [] })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible forma podría ser usando `Object.keys()` e iterar el objeto a partir de las propiedades 0, 1, 2 .. etc.

```js
const obj = [{"0":{"modelo":"E40JMHL","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.","total":1},"1":{"modelo":"F6CMHS","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.","total":2},"2":{"modelo":"F150FETX","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1},"3":{"modelo":"F20CMHS","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1},"4":{"modelo":"F25GMHL","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1}}];

let data_modelo = [];

let data_total = [];

let data_empresa = [];

Object.keys(obj[0]).forEach(e => {
  data_modelo.push(obj[0][e].modelo);
  data_total.push(obj[0][e].total);
  data_empresa.push(obj[0][e].nombre_empresa);
});

console.log(data_modelo);
console.log(data_total);
console.log(data_empresa);
```

También puedes poner todo en un solo objeto, que quizá es mas conveniente, en ese caso se puede usar `reduce()`

```js
const obj = [{"0":{"modelo":"E40JMHL","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.","total":1},"1":{"modelo":"F6CMHS","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIAL DITEN LTDA.","total":2},"2":{"modelo":"F150FETX","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1},"3":{"modelo":"F20CMHS","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1},"4":{"modelo":"F25GMHL","nombre_empresa":"COMERCIO LTDA","total":1}}];


const res = Object.keys(obj[0]).reduce((p,c) => {
  p.data_modelo.push(obj[0][c].modelo);
  p.data_total.push(obj[0][c].total);
  p.data_empresa.push(obj[0][c].nombre_empresa);
  return p;
},{data_modelo:[],data_total:[],data_empresa:[]});

console.log(res);
```